# How to expand a code to delete files via python glob for multiple filetypes?

Tags: python, file, pycharm, glob, delete-file

I've done the following code to delete one filetype in a directory and its sub directories using python. But I need to expand it for multiple file types. Can anybody help me?

`import os import glob fileList = glob.glob('D:\\analises para integrar\\pasta para teste do scrip\\**\\*.bin', recursive=True) for filePath in fileList: try: os.remove(filePath) except OSError: print("Error while deleting file")`

Answer (score 0):

Please take the time to format your code correctly when posting in the future.

[Globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). You can imagine the `*` you use before `.bin` to be recognized as any number of any number of any character. So if you want to glob another type of file, replace the `.bin` portion with any extension you want and it will be captured the same way.